# How would I go about determining if an integer is a multiple of 2 but not a multiple of 3 print ‘<myint > is a multiple of 2 only.’ ? Using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, if-statement, boolean

How would I go about determining if an integer is a multiple of 2 but not a multiple of 3 print ‘ is a multiple of 2 only.’ ? Using python.

```
if myint%2: 
    print(str(myint), "is a multiple of 2 only")
```

How do I get it to output "but not a multiple of 3"

Comment: This is FizzBuzz. It is very popular. Please Google it.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing

```
your_number%2 == 0 and your_number%3 != 0
```

Where `%` is the modulus operator and divides left hand operand by right hand operand and returns the remainder. So if the remainder is equal to `0`, the left operand is a multiple of the right operand.

Thus

`your_number%2 == 0` returns `True` if `your_number` is a multiple of 2

and

`your_number%3 != 0` returns `True` if `your_number` is not a multiple of 3.

To provide you with a full answer, what you need is:

```
if myint%2 == 0 and myintr%3 != 0:
    print(str(myint), "is a multiple of 2 and not a multiple of 3")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

```
#first checks if myint / 2 doesn't has a reminder
#then checks if myint / 3 has a reminder
if not myint % 2 and myint % 3: 
    print(myint,"is a multiple of 2 only")
```

or if you want:

```
if myint % 2 == 0 and myint % 3 != 0: 
    print(myint,"is a multiple of 2 only")
```

Both work the same

Comment: Your True/False evaluation style is a [*don't* for Python Program at Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=True/False_evaluations#True/False_evaluations). I mean your `if not myint % 2`.

Comment: there isn't anything wrong with it